# jQuery masonry not stacking (gaps between items in vertical columns)

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

I first tried Masonry by myself, but there were gaps between the div items. so then I tried using the exact same code from http://jsbin.com/inunin/3/edit, from this tutorial: jaxenter.com/tutorial-get-a-tiled-layout-with-jquery-plugins-43514.html.

All I did was add content to the inside, but there are gaps between them again, like the first time I tried:

`jsbin.com/hireturi/3/edit`

How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Comment: please show us what you have tried like a jsfiddle or some code so we can help

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic for not having an example in the question itself.